# Can't seem to install rubocop gem using Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubocop

I tried installing rubocop by adding the suggested line to my Rails project's Gemfile:

`gem 'rubocop', require: false`

After running `bundle`, it installs and is visible in my Gemfile.lock.

However when running `$ rubocop` from my application's root I receive this error:

`-bash: rubocop: command not found`

I tried running `$ which rubocop`, and nothing comes up.

I've also tried running `$ gem install rubocop`, with no difference in behavior.

Here is the excerpt from my Gemfile.lock:

```
rubocop (0.27.0)
  astrolabe (~> 1.3)
  parser (>= 2.2.0.pre.6, < 3.0)
  powerpack (~> 0.0.6)
  rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
  ruby-progressbar (~> 1.4)
```

Comment: Maybe `rubocop` isn't yet loaded in environment. Try doing: `source ~/.bashrc` and then run: `$ rubocop`

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks a bunch. I haven't had to do a reload in the past to get a gem to install like this. Any ideas as to why that would occur?

Comment: Added the reason in answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was wondering how to close it out..

Comment: Umm.. click the red "x" window button to close and click on terminal icon to open it again.

Comment: Oh, I meant my question on SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to run this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

As right after running `$ bundle` command the gem was installed and its environment was set in your `~/.bashrc`, but since you continued to use the old bash session you didn't get `rubocop` available as a command in your bash. Hence, either re-login in your bash(close and then open the terminal again) or run the command stated above.